# what software can draw this kind of figure?

Tags: diagrams

It looks very beautiful! I'd love it! See http://www.science4all.org/le-nguyen-hoang/integer-programming/

Do someone know what software can draw this kind of figure? I'm interested in learning it.

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: It might be created by PSTricks.

Comment: –1: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document. Notify me with the @ syntax, when you added a MWE and I'd be happy to redeem my down vote ;-)

Comment: Start with this: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/j-curve/

Comment: @Tobi Thanks for your kindly reminder. Actually I just want to know which software can do that. I don't mean to draw this figure. :)

Comment: I'm the one who did the figure. I used Inkscape.
I'm glad you like it!
Cheers,
Lê.

Comment: Hmmm … then this question is kind of too broad (’cause there are plenty of softwares able to draw this), too localized (i.e. there would be few benefits for later visitors, or even off-topic (Inkskape insn’t in the scope of this site, for example). So in fact this question _could_ be closed for three reasons, in my eyes ;-) And for that the question can be only helpful if someone draws the figure for you, which makes it a “do it for me” question …

Comment: I hope you don’t mind and take it personal, but in the last months there came up more and more questions of this kind and I think they aren’t in the spirit of TeX.SX and not very rewarding for the future. So donwvoting is the way I decided to deal with it … sorry ;-)

Comment: @Tobi OK, I don't ask this kind of questions any more. :)

Comment: Thats great :-) Unfortunately I can’T redeem my downvote until the question is edited …

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Remarks

The picture looks a lot, like it was done using [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) (I think, I can tell because of the arrows).

I recreated your drawing using the almighty `tikz`.

## Implementation

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every path/.style={}]
    \begin{scope}
        \shade[right color=green,left color=white,opacity=0.7] (-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (0,6.5);
        \node[rotate=90,above] at (0,3) {Non-Negative Gold};
        \shade[top color=yellow,bottom color=white,opacity=0.7] (-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (8.5,0);
        \node[below] at (4,0) {Non-Negative Bills};
        \shade[left color=red,bottom color=red,right color=white,opacity=0.5] (-0.5,5.5) -- (8.5,3) -- (8.5,6.5) -- (-0.5,6.5) -- cycle;
        \path (-0.5,5.5) -- node[pos=0.23,sloped,above] {Volume Constraint} (8.5,3);
        \shade[left color=blue,right color=white,opacity=0.5] (2.5,6.5) -- (8.5,6.5) -- (8.5,0) -- (5,0) -- cycle;
        \path (5,0) -- node[pos=0.3,sloped,above] {Weight Constraint} (2.5,6.5);
        \node[text width=7em,align=center] at (2,2) {Feasible Region of the Linear Relaxation};
        \draw[->] (-0.5,0) -- (8.5,0) node[below] {Gold bars};
        \draw[->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,6.5) node[above] {Bill stacks};
        \node[rotate=-45,above,text width=9em,align=center] at (7.25,5.25) {Level Curves of the Objective Function};
        \path[clip] (-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (8.5,6.5);
        \foreach \i in {0.5,3,...,13} {
            \draw[help lines] (-0.5,\i) -- +(-45:15);
        }
    \end{scope}
    \draw[very thick,->] (9,3.25) -- node[above,text width=4cm,align=center] {\Large\bfseries Add Integrality Constraints} (13,3.25);
    \begin{scope}[shift={(14,0)}]
        \shade[right color=green,left color=white,opacity=0.7] (-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (0,6.5);
        \shade[top color=yellow,bottom color=white,opacity=0.7] (-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (8.5,0);
        \shade[left color=red,bottom color=red,right color=white,opacity=0.5] (-0.5,5.5) -- (8.5,3) -- (8.5,6.5) -- (-0.5,6.5) -- cycle;
        \shade[left color=blue,right color=white,opacity=0.5] (2.5,6.5) -- (8.5,6.5) -- (8.5,0) -- (5,0) -- cycle;
        \draw[->] (-0.5,0) -- (8.5,0) node[below] {Gold bars};
        \draw[->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,6.5) node[above] {Bill stacks};
        \foreach \i in {0,1,...,6.5} {
            \draw[help lines] (-0.5,\i) -- (8.5,\i);
        }
        \foreach \i in {2,4,...,8.5} {
            \draw[help lines] (\i,6.5) -- (\i,-0.5);
        }
        \foreach \i in {0,1,...,5} {
            \node[draw,cross out,label={left:\i}] at (0,\i) {};
        }
        \foreach \i in {0,1,...,4} {
            \node[draw,cross out] at (2,\i) {};
        }
        \foreach \i in {0,1,...,2} {
            \node[draw,cross out] at (4,\i) {};
        }
        \foreach \i in {0,2,...,6} {
            \node[below] at (\i,0) {\pgfmathparse{int(\i/2)}\pgfmathresult};
        }
        \node[very thick,draw=black,fill=white,rectangle,rounded corners,text width=8em,align=center] at (6,5) {Feasible solutions of the integer program are the crosses};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Thank you. Actually, that's not meant to be a joke. Personally I think, that I can spot differences between arrows produced by Inkscape, TikZ and Metapost.

Answer (score 4):

Just a starting point with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-slpe}

\begin{document}
\psset{xunit=2cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-.5,-.5)(4.5,6.5)
    \psgrid[gridcolor=lightgray,subgriddiv=1,gridlabels=0](-.5,-.5)(4,6)
    \bgroup
        \psset{linestyle=none,linewidth=0,fillstyle=slope,slopesteps=500,fading}
        \psframe[slopebegin=white,slopeend=green](-.5,-.5)(0,6)
        \psframe[slopebegin=white,slopeend=yellow,slopeangle=90](-.5,-.5)(4,0)
        \pspolygon[slopebegin=red,slopeend=red!50!white,startfading=0,endfading=.7](-.5,5.8)(-.5,6)(4,6)(4,2)
    \egroup
    \psaxes[ticks=none]{->}(0,0)(-.5,-.5)(4,6)[\parbox{2cm}{\scriptsize Gold Bars},-90][\parbox{3cm}{\scriptsize \centering Bill\\ Stacks},90]
    \bgroup
        \psset{dotstyle=x,dotscale=2}
        \multido{\i=0+1}{6}{\psdots(0,\i)}
    \egroup
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]